# Customize toggle button in Bootstrap using only CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a demo that uses the toggle dropdown button of bootstrap. I've customized the bootstrap.css but not boostrap.js. Can I use toggle without boostrap.js?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/456/)

Here is the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#firstvalue').addClass('user-click');
  $('#usr').val("(" + $("#firstTag").text() + ")");
  $('#demolist li a').on('click', function() {
    $('.user-click').removeClass('user-click');
    $(this).find('.user-check').addClass('user-click');
    $('#usr').val("(" + $(this).text() + ")");
  });
});
```

```css
.user-check {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  outline: 0 none;
  padding: 8px 5px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  width: 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}
.user-click:before {
  bottom: 10px;
  content: "\2713";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  transition: all 1s ease-out 0s;
  width: 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #444444;
}
.btnAlpha-inverse {
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #444444;
  border-color: #444444;
  /*set the color you want here*/
}
.btnAlpha-inverse:hover,
.btnAlpha-inverse:focus,
.btnAlpha-inverse:active,
.btnAlpha-inverse.active,
.btnAlpha-inverse.disabled,
.btnAlpha-inverse[disabled] {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #444444;
  *background-color: #444444;
}
.btnAlpha-small {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  font-size: 11.9px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.dropdown-header {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #444444;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a,
.dropdown-submenu:focus>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444444;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f5f5f5);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f5f5f5), to(#f5f5f5));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f5f5f5);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f5f5f5);
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3); */
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-lg>.btnAlpha,
.btnAlpha-lg {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-sm>.btnAlpha,
.btnAlpha-sm {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-xs>.btnAlpha,
.btnAlpha-xs {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px
}
.btnAlpha-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha {
  position: relative;
  float: left
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha.active,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha:active,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha:focus,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha:hover,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha.active,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha:active,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha:focus,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha:hover {
  z-index: 2
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha .btnAlpha+.btnAlpha,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha .btnAlpha+.btnAlpha-groupAlpha,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha .btnAlpha-groupAlpha+.btnAlpha,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha .btnAlpha-groupAlpha+.btnAlpha-groupAlpha {
  margin-left: -1px
}
.btnAlpha-toolbar {
  margin-left: -5px
}
.btnAlpha-toolbar .btnAlpha,
.btnAlpha-toolbar .btnAlpha-groupAlpha,
.btnAlpha-toolbar .input-group {
  float: left
}
.btnAlpha-toolbar>.btnAlpha,
.btnAlpha-toolbar>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha,
.btnAlpha-toolbar>.input-group {
  margin-left: 5px
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
  border-radius: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha:first-child {
  margin-left: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha:first-child:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha:last-child:not(:first-child),
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.dropdown-toggle:not(:first-child) {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha {
  float: left
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)>.btnAlpha {
  border-radius: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha:first-child:not(:last-child)>.btnAlpha:last-child,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha:first-child:not(:last-child)>.dropdown-toggle {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha:last-child:not(:first-child)>.btnAlpha:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha .dropdown-toggle:active,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha.open .dropdown-toggle {
  outline: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha+.dropdown-toggle {
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha-lg+.dropdown-toggle {
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha.open .dropdown-toggle {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha.open .dropdown-toggle.btnAlpha-link {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none
}
.btnAlpha .caret {
  margin-left: 0
}
.btnAlpha-lg .caret {
  border-width: 5px 5px 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0
}
.dropup .btnAlpha-lg .caret {
  border-width: 0 5px 5px
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha {
  float: none
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha+.btnAlpha,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha+.btnAlpha-groupAlpha,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha+.btnAlpha,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha+.btnAlpha-groupAlpha {
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  border-radius: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha:first-child:not(:last-child) {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha:last-child:not(:first-child) {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)>.btnAlpha {
  border-radius: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha:first-child:not(:last-child)>.btnAlpha:last-child,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha:first-child:not(:last-child)>.dropdown-toggle {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha:last-child:not(:first-child)>.btnAlpha:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-justified {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-justified>.btnAlpha,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-justified>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  width: 1%
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-justified>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha .btnAlpha {
  width: 100%
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-justified>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha .dropdown-menu {
  left: auto
}
[data-toggle=buttons]>.btnAlpha input[type=checkbox],
[data-toggle=buttons]>.btnAlpha input[type=radio],
[data-toggle=buttons]>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha input[type=checkbox],
[data-toggle=buttons]>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  pointer-events: none
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha,
.input-group-btnAlpha:first-child>.dropdown-toggle,
.input-group-btnAlpha:last-child>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha:not(:last-child)>.btnAlpha,
.input-group-btnAlpha:last-child>.btnAlpha:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0
}
.input-group-addon:first-child {
  border-right: 0
}
.input-group .form-control:last-child,
.input-group-addon:last-child,
.input-group-btnAlpha:first-child>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha:not(:first-child)>.btnAlpha,
.input-group-btnAlpha:first-child>.btnAlpha:not(:first-child),
.input-group-btnAlpha:last-child>.btnAlpha,
.input-group-btnAlpha:last-child>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha>.btnAlpha,
.input-group-btnAlpha:last-child>.dropdown-toggle {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0
}
.input-group-addon:last-child {
  border-left: 0
}
.input-group-btnAlpha {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap
}
.input-group-btnAlpha>.btnAlpha {
  position: relative
}
.input-group-btnAlpha>.btnAlpha+.btnAlpha {
  margin-left: -1px
}
.input-group-btnAlpha>.btnAlpha:active,
.input-group-btnAlpha>.btnAlpha:focus,
.input-group-btnAlpha>.btnAlpha:hover {
  z-index: 2
}
.input-group-btnAlpha:first-child>.btnAlpha,
.input-group-btnAlpha:first-child>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha {
  margin-right: -1px
}
.input-group-btnAlpha:last-child>.btnAlpha,
.input-group-btnAlpha:last-child>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha {
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: -1px
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha .btnAlpha+.btnAlpha {
  margin-left: -1px
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha:after,
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha:before,
.btnAlpha-toolbar:after,
.btnAlpha-toolbar:before,
.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before,
.container-fluid:after,
.container-fluid:before,
.container:after,
.container:before,
.dl-horizontal dd:after,
.dl-horizontal dd:before,
.form-horizontal .form-group:after,
.form-horizontal .form-group:before,
.modal-footer:after,
.modal-footer:before,
.nav:after,
.nav:before,
.navbar-collapse:after,
.navbar-collapse:before,
.navbar-header:after,
.navbar-header:before,
.navbar:after,
.navbar:before,
.pager:after,
.pager:before,
.panel-body:after,
.panel-body:before,
.row:after,
.row:before {
  display: table;
  content: " "
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-vertical>.btnAlpha-groupAlpha:after,
.btnAlpha-toolbar:after,
.clearfix:after,
.container-fluid:after,
.container:after,
.dl-horizontal dd:after,
.form-horizontal .form-group:after,
.modal-footer:after,
.nav:after,
.navbar-collapse:after,
.navbar-header:after,
.navbar:after,
.pager:after,
.panel-body:after,
.row:after {
  clear: both
}
.btnAlpha-groupAlpha-xs>.btnAlpha .badge,
.btnAlpha-xs .badge {
  top: 0;
  padding: 1px 5px
}
a.badge:focus,
a.badge:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer
}
.open>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-header {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #444444;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.list-unstyled {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none
}
.list-inline {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  list-style: none
}
.list-inline>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown btnAlpha-groupAlpha">
  <button class="btnAlpha btnAlpha-small btnAlpha-inverse dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    V
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="demolist">
    <li class="dropdown-header">Search in:</li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="firstTag">
        <div class="user-check" id="firstvalue"></div>Korean</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="user-check"></div>Chinese</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="user-check"></div>Japanese</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `customize` here ? What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @JSantosh: here is my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/456/. I use bootstrap.js library for coding.  Now, I want to the toggle dropdown working well without bootstrap library, so I need to customize code and remove bootstrap library

Comment: You want use bootstrap dropdown functionality without bootstrap js. then simply you can use the dropdown code only  from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/js/dropdown.js). It is just 170 lines of code.

Comment: @JSantosh: Thank you, Is it Integrated with boostrap.css ? I've removed boostrap.js and add dropdown.js but not work well.

Comment: yes of-course it is integrated. as you said you don't want to use JS , so i gave only JS file. can you update the fiddle give the  new link

Comment: @JSantosh: Here is the new demo with dropdown.js. Please help me review it: http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/463/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89646/discussion-between-phm-quc-bo-and-j-santosh).